# Find Jordan basis and jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, change-of-basis

Linear transformation $\varphi$ from space $\mathbf{R}_n$ in basis $\mathbf{e}_1\ldots\mathbf{e}_n$ is given by matrix:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}3 & 2 & -3 \\ 4 &10 & -12 \\ 3 & 6 &-7\end{pmatrix}$$

I have to find basis $\mathbf{f}_1\ldots\mathbf{f}_n$ in which given matrix has Jordan form $A_j$ and find Jordan form itself.

Which steps should I reproduce to find both?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thats actually only about basis

Comment: Then you also have the Jordan form, see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236159/finding-jordan-canonical-form-for-3x3-matrix), and many others.

Comment: Do you not have access to any material where this sort of problem is discussed? Notes from lectures you have attended? or a textbook?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I really know only that I have to find $\mathrm{det}|A-{\lambda}I|$ first, then eigenvalues.

Comment: Good. Then that's probably what you should do first, and present your results when you post your question. It always helps people to answer a question, when they know what the person asking the question has already done.